# Advantage of the components apart from the three main ones

Tags: openmdao

What is the advantage of using the components from OpenMDAO's standard library
(i.e. matrixvectorproduct, dotproduct, linearsystem,  [etc](http://openmdao.org/twodocs/versions/latest/features/building_blocks/components/index.html))?

As far as I understand, all of them are based on the two base classes: ExplicitComponent and ImplicitComponent

Is there a reason one should use them apart from convenience?

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. Do you mean to ask what the advantage is for using the already implemented components in the OpenMDAO standard library?

Answer (score 2):

The OpenMDAO standard library of components provides a set of helful, general use components, all vectorized, and all with verified-to-be-correct analytic derivatives. You're certainly not required or even obligated to use them at all. However, these components are ones that appear again and again inside many different models that have been built.

Their common appearance motivated us to generalize their implementations and include them in the standard library to avoid the need to either re-implement the components each time, or copy/paste the existing implementation into a new project. 
Duplicating code in general is a bad idea, so whenever you can abstract something to be more general and broadly useable is a good idea.

If you are smart about how you leverage these components, you can implement some very complex calculations without the need to write the nonlinear or linear code yourself. The [Dymos](https://github.com/OpenMDAO/dymos/tree/f42170ba7112130292ba37b6cda26e23ce1a2980) version 0.10.0 and [OpenConcept](https://github.com/mdolab/openconcept/tree/e2d9bbd737c2e1fbd97e60d4979185c7f08ec5a4) libraries, built on top of OpenMDAO, use these components extensively to reduce their own coding burdens.

Comment: As far as I checked those two repositories (looked for 'Comp' or similar with grep command) they use only the three main components (Explicit, Implicit, Indepvar). My question was the usage of MatrixvectorproductComp, dotproductComp, LinearsystemComp or similar components. I guess the first part of your answer is the thing that I am looking for. These extra components provide analytical gradients and they are vectorized automatically. This makes them more attractive than writing your own ExplicitComponent for (i.e.) a linear matrix solver and trying to make it more efficient. is this right?